# JSP page appear without CSS style

Tags: css, spring, jsp

My JSP page is working but it appear without css style, somebody had problem like this ?

I declared mvc resources like:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/" />
```

And in JSP page:

```
<head>
<title>Auctions site</title>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/mystyle.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Files structure :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkPoH.png)

Comment: Try moving  directory structure `resource/css/mystyle.css` under `webapp` folder and then access your application.

Comment: It works ! Thank you !

Comment: cool..you are welcome  :)